# Android-клиент не принимает информацию

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, android-studio

Всем доброго времени суток. И опять я мучусь с этим клиентом. Есть первая активити. В ней сразу объявлен класс

```
Conect conect = new Conect();
```

а в методе  onCreate прописан запуск:

```
conect.start();
```

Вот сам класс Conect :

```
public class Conect extends Thread {

Socket client;
String address = "192.168.1.23";
String port = "8888";
String coment;
String a;
InetAddress ipAddress;
BufferedReader in;
PrintWriter out;

//открываю новый поток
@Override
//то что должно запускаться в новом потоке
public void run() {

    try {
        ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(address); // создаем объект который отображает вышеописанный IP-адрес.
        client = new Socket(ipAddress, Integer.parseInt(port)); // создаем сокет используя IP-адрес и порт сервера.
        //переменная для получение данных
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        //переменная для отправки данных
        out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);

        //Если это здесь, то все отправляет и принимает.
        out.println("Fight");
        a = in.readLine();


        setComent("Успешное подключение к " + address + ":" + port + "...");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        setComent("Не удалось подключится к " + address + ":" + port + " ошибка номер №: " + e);
    }
}

public void CloseConect () {out.println("END");}

public void Summ () {
    //отсюда отправляется
    out.println("Summ");

   //а если я хочу получить здесь, то андроид-устройство выдает ошибку
   try {
        a = in.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void setComent(String coment) {this.coment = coment;}
```

}

Суть в том. Если без каких либо кнопок, то все конектится, данные отравляются и получаются.

Но если вставить в обработчик в активити на кнопочку:

```
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // по id определяем кнопку, вызвавшую этот обработчик
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case  R.id.btnFight:
                conect.Summ();
    }
}
```

Я не спеша жду, когда мне сервер сообщит, что клиент соединился, что он отправил запрос на суммирование, но потом андроид выдает Ошибку приложения и ругается именно на conect.Summ(); в обработчике нажатия и a = in.readLine(); в методе Summ().

Пожалуйста подскажите, что я делаю не так.
Второе, как найти в Android Studio лог моей ошибки??
И последнее. Если я отправляю через андроид кириллицу, то на сервере я получаю вот такое - РџСЂРёРІРµС‚  а если с сервера на андроид, то получаю черные ромбики со знаком вопроса. Хотя что в IDEA, что в Android Studio в правом нижнем углу стоит UTF-8. У меня есть аналог клиент, который я запускаю с IDEA, то обмен кириллицей происходит без проблем. Подскажите пожалуйста как решить эту проблему. Заранее всем спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в вызове метода **Summ** происходит оттого, что вы не запустили, собственно, поток до вызова сего метода. Засим у вас все переменные класса не инициализированы.

Вам надо сначала инициализировать переменные, потом запустить поток, а потом уже что-то с ним делать.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Значит я тогда не совсем понимаю. Ведь в методе Summ, отправка сообщения серверу out.println("Summ"); происходит нормально.